# finding difference between two data set

Tags: correlation, dataset

I have a data set that has 160 attributes, after I check for correlation and I used trim like

```
> tmp <- cor(data)

> tmp[upper.tri(tmp)] <- 0

> diag(tmp) <- 0

> data.new <- data[,!apply(tmp,2,function(x) any(x > 0.99))]
```

Now my data set has 135 attributes and that is good, but is there any way that I can find out which attributes were eliminated without looking manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setdiff(colnames(data), colnames(data.new))
```

This however is more suited for stackoverflow than here.